# ionic ion-google-place ng-model undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, google-places-api

I'm trying to submit the ng model in my ion-google-place directive but it always logs undefined

view:

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">

 <ion-google-place placeholder="Enter Address" ng-model="location" geocode-options="geocodeOptions"/>

 <button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>

</form>
```

controller:

```
$scope.submit = function(){
      var location = $scope.location;
     console.log(location);
     }
```

Comment: You missed `"` of `ng-click` on `button`

Comment: @Tushar oh sorry, but that's not really the issue

Comment: You didn't call `submit` function on `ng-click` of `button`

Comment: @Tushar sorry for the typo.. assume no syntax error

Answer (score 0):

View:

```
<form ng-submit="submit(location)">
   <ion-google-place placeholder="Enter Address" ng-model="location" geocode-options="geocodeOptions"/>
   <button ng-click="submit(location)">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.submit = function(location) {
    var loc = location;
    console.log(loc);
}
```

This should work.